# How to use interface with generic object?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm getting trouble in using the interface I create. I try to implement it but there an error occur. Any answer is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here the actual Interface I want to implement.

```
namespace CRDM.Core.Models
{
  [Table("cities")]
  public class City : ICity<CountryState>
  {
  }

  [Table("country_states")]
  public class CountryState : ICountryState<Country>
  {        
  }

  [Table("countries")]
  public class Country : ICountry
  {       
  }
}

namespace CRDM.Core.Abstractions.Entities
{
 public interface ICity <TState> :
    where TState : ICountryState<ICountry>
 {
    TState StateReference { get; set; }
 }

 public interface ICountryState<TCountry> :
    where TCountry : ICountry
 {

 }

 public interface ICountry
 {
 }
}
```

I successfully implement the `Country` and `CountryState` class, but there an error in the implementation of `City`. Here the error message.

> The type `CRDM.Core.Models.CountryState` cannot be used as type
>   parameter `TState` in the generic type or method `ICity<TState>`.
>
> There is no implicit reference conversion from
>   `CRDM.Core.Models.CountryState`  to
>   `CRDM.Core.Abstractions.Entities.ICountryState<CRDM.Core.Abstractions.Entities.ICountry>`.

Comment: I'm afraid that something is wrong with the way that you're trying to use generics. It looks like you're thinking of having different classes for different countries or states. Or maybe you're trying to use the generic arguments as a way to relate cities to states to countries, etc. I could be totally wrong. But if that's the case then it's probably good to take a step back and see if there's a different way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is a common error with generics: you assume that `ICountryState<Country>` can be casted as `ICountryState<ICountry>` but it can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```
namespace CRDM.Core.Models
{

    public class City : ICity<CountryState,Country>
    {
        public CountryState StateReference { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }


    public class CountryState : ICountryState<Country>
    {
    }


    public class Country : ICountry
    {
    }
}

namespace CRDM.Core.Abstractions.Entities
{
    public interface ICity<TState,TCountry>        
       where TCountry: ICountry
       where TState : ICountryState<TCountry>
    {
        TState StateReference { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICountryState<TCountry>        
       where TCountry : ICountry
    {

    }

    public interface ICountry
    {
    }
}
```

Or this way:

```
    namespace CRDM.Core.Models
    {
        public class City : ICity<CountryState>
        {
            public CountryState StateReference { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public class CountryState : ICountryState<ICountry>
        {
        }

        public class Country : ICountry
        {
        }
    }

    namespace CRDM.Core.Abstractions.Entities
    {
        public interface ICity<TState> 

           where TState : ICountryState<ICountry>
        {
            TState StateReference { get; set; }
        }

        public interface ICountryState<TCountry> 

           where TCountry : ICountry
        {

        }

        public interface ICountry
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to ask yourself what are you trying to achieve and  are you simply making this more complicated than it needs to be.  If you want to access these entities using interfaces but make them work with entity framework I would do...

```
namespace CRDM.Core.Models
{
    using CRDM.Core.Abstractions.Entities;

    [Table("cities")]
    public class City : ICity
    {
        public CountryState StateReference { get; set; }
        ICountryState ICity.StateReference
        {
            get
            {
                return StateReference;
            }
            set
            {
                StateReference = (CountryState)value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Table("country_states")]
    public class CountryState : ICountryState
    {
        public Country Country { get; set; }
        ICountry ICountryState.Country
        {
            get
            {
                return Country;
            }
            set
            {
                Country = (Country)value;
            }
        }
    }

    [Table("countries")]
    public class Country : ICountry
    {
    }
}

namespace CRDM.Core.Abstractions.Entities
{
    public interface ICity
    {
        ICountryState StateReference { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICountryState
    {
        ICountry Country { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICountry
    {
    }
}
```